# How to copy registry keys for this?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, group-policy

I wanted to restrict access to a particular program, for which I used Software Restriction Policy in the Group Policy Editor. I want to do this on multiple computers so I tracked down the registry key which was being changed. My question is that if I export this folder and add it to the registry in another computer, will it work? I'm doubtful because its location looks like this:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects\
**{0FA46651-D40D-495C-8771-B350B94AD114}Machine\**
Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Safer\CodeIdentifiers\0\Hashes`

I am worried about the part that is emphasized. Will it be the same in other computers? Can you suggest a better way to do this?

**EDIT**: The location of the Hash Rules keeps changing. I added another hash rule some time later and it went to a different `{randomnumbers}Machine` folder. Also, the Hash folder that I exported earlier does not impose the required software restrictions if I merge it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Security Compliance Manager from Microsoft, its free. Then make sure to look in the installation folder and install the LocalGPO Tool. Security Compliance Manager is a GUI LocalGPO tools is a script that can be used to share group policies with offline PCs. Just make sure you read thru the documentation, FAQ, properly for your specific case to prove the tools can be beneficial to you.

SCM https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16776